# IdentityServer4 and Seperate User Authentication Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to make use to IdentityServer4 for authentication and authorization. We have set of new and existing applications.

At this moment in time we have: 
 - 1 ReactJs application - (there is no authentication as it's a new application) but it will use Implicit Flow using oidc-client
 - 1 quite old Web Form application - which will possibly use Hybrid flow (I still need to figure it out)
 - 2 .NetCore MVC web applications - they both will use Hybrid Flow

- There are Few apis project that we want to protect using IDS4.

WebForm and MVC Applications both uses their own Web Services to talk to the some database to verify user credentials and let the user login to the application.

Eventually we want to migrate users from that existing database to a seperate User database. IdentityServer will also make use of this new User Database for SSO + Api Authrization.

I am thinking of creating a seperate api just for User Authentication (possibly AspNetIdentity as a webapi) and IdentityServer4 to communicate with this api to validate username/password? Does that seems right?

Also How do I configure IDServer4 to use Api for authentication rather than using services.AddIdentityServer().AddAspNetIdentity() which will directly talk to my AspNewIdentity database? and How to sure this api? Any samples I can find?

Comment: Why don't you want to host IdSrv4 with Identity in the same application?

Comment: because I want to keep them seperate ...many reasons
1. Identity Api can potentialy talk to multiple Databases to authenticate the user
2. Admin UserManagement App can make use to this api directly via IdServer access token for things like create user, reset password, lock users, manage roles and permissions..

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this, I found these useful

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

I used it to protect an api via users that came from Asp Identity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 doesn't really do users out of the box. The ASP.Net Identity integration just exists to get you up and running quickly. If you want to implement your own user store and sign in/out/up flows then you're totally free to do that however you want.

That said, I'm a fan of having the IDP own its own data - i.e. the users and their credentials. This helps keep you on the straight and narrow when it comes to not mixing authentication and authorization. The Auth in OAuth is *client* authorization don't forget.

Comment: are there any samples where I can define Custom User Store as a API. 

Also do I have a explicitly call api end point using HttpClient in IdServer Account controller to validate the user? what access tokens?

and since IdServer will be making a request to this APi, how can I secure this api and should I create a client as 'identityServer' with in IdentityServer? and Api is secure using IdServer?

Comment: @hanz did you find a solution to your query to use custom user store / authentication as an external API?